# How to change the color of the selected option text?

Tags: css, html, select, drop-down-menu

I have created an HTML form using bootstrap and some CSS. I have a select box. When a user selects an option it needs to change the color to white. Currently, the text color is Black. I need to change it to White. I tried most of the things but nothing worked.

Here is the code,

```
<div class="wrap-input1001 validate-input">
     <select name="accType" class="form-control" placeholder="Choose One Thing">
             <option></option>
             <option value="RD">RD</option>
             <option value="BS">BS</option>
             <option value="TW">TW</option>
             <option value="AP">AP</option>
      </select>
 </div>
```

Here is the image,
[image]

CSS Code,

```
.select2-container--bootstrap4 .select2-selection--single{height:calc(2.25rem + 2px)!important}.select2-container--bootstrap4 .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__placeholder{color:#CBB0FC;line-height:2.25rem}.select2-container--bootstrap4 .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow{position:absolute;top:50%;right:3px;width:20px}.select2-container--bootstrap4 .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b{top:60%;border-color:#fff transparent transparent;border-style:solid;border-width:5px 4px 0;width:0;height:0;left:50%;margin-left:-4px;margin-top:-2px;position:absolute}.select2-container--bootstrap4 .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered{line-height:2.25rem}.select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field{border:1px solid #ced4da;border-radius:.25rem}.select2-results__message{color:#6c757d}.select2-container--bootstrap4 .select2-selection--multiple{min-height:calc(2.25rem + 2px)!important}.select2-container--bootstrap4 .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__rendered{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0 5px;width:100%}.select2-container--bootstrap4 .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice{color:#343a40;border:1px solid #bdc6d0;border-radius:.2rem;padding:0 5px 0 0;cursor:pointer;float:left;margin-top:.3em;margin-right:5px}.select2-container--bootstrap4 .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove{color:#bdc6d0;font-weight:700;margin-left:3px;margin-right:1px;padding-right:3px;padding-left:3px;float:left}.select2-container--bootstrap4 .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove:hover{color:#343a40}.select2-container :focus{outline:0}.select2-container--bootstrap4 .select2-selection{border:1px solid #ced4da;border-radius:.25rem;width:100%}.select2-container--bootstrap4.select2-container--focus .select2-selection{border-color:#17a2b8;-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(0,123,255,.25);box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(0,123,255,.25)}.select2-container--bootstrap4.select2-container--focus.select2-container--open .select2-selection{border-bottom:none;border-bottom-left-radius:0;border-bottom-right-radius:0}select.is-invalid~.select2-container--bootstrap4 .select2-selection{border-color:#dc3545}select.is-valid~.select2-container--bootstrap4 .select2-selection{border-color:#28a745}.select2-container--bootstrap4 .select2-dropdown{border-color:#ced4da;border-top:none;border-top-left-radius:0;border-top-right-radius:0}.select2-container--bootstrap4 .select2-dropdown .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true]{background-color:#e9ecef;}.select2-container--bootstrap4 .select2-results__option--highlighted,.select2-container--bootstrap4 .select2-results__option--highlighted.select2-results__option[aria-selected=true]{background-color:#007bff;color:#f8f9fa}.select2-container--bootstrap4 .select2-results__option[role=group]{padding:0}.select2-container--bootstrap4 .select2-results__options{max-height:15em;overflow-y:auto}.select2-container--bootstrap4 .select2-results__group{padding:6px;display:list-item;color:#6c757d}.select2-container--bootstrap4 .select2-selection__clear{width:1.2em;height:1.2em;line-height:1.15em;padding-left:.3em;margin-top:.5em;border-radius:100%;background-color:#6c757d;color:#f8f9fa;float:right;margin-right:.3em}.select2-container--bootstrap4 .select2-selection__clear:hover{background-color:#343a40}
```

Comment: Please provide your CSS code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add code something like this:

```css
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered { color: #FFF; }
```

OR check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/973rmq8j/):

Comment: No, Your CSS is minified that's why I have added example CSS code.

Comment: You need to increase the selector wait. like: 'select.form-control'. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. But It also didn't work. What I only need is to change the text color from black to white.

Comment: Yes, I added. But text color won't change.

Comment: I think you have used the select2 js library.  That's why the simple select code is not working for you. In that case, you need to add CSS as per the select2 structure and selectors.

Comment: Yes, So How can I do that? Can you help me? I tried and I change the color of the Placeholder also. But I need to change the text color. When in the dropdown, black color is ok. But once I selected a value It should be white.

Comment: Please try: .select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered { color: #FFF; }